# How to move all files and folders from current directory to another directory excluding a folder named "My Folder" in vb?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I want to move all files and folders from current directory to another directory excluding a folder named "My Folder". I want to know how can I do this with vb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really tested but might be helpful anyway:

```
Dim currentDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() ' or whatever you call current
Dim targetDir = Path.Combine(currentDir, "Target-Directory")
Directory.CreateDirectory(targetDir)

Dim allDirs = From dir In Directory.EnumerateDirectories(currentDir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
              Where Not Path.GetFileName(dir).Equals("My Folder", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
For Each dir As String In allDirs
    Try
        Dim targetPath As String = Path.Combine(targetDir, Path.GetFileName(dir))
        Directory.Move(dir, targetPath)
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' log or whatever, here just ignore and continue ...
    End Try
Next

'now move the rest of the files in the troot folder
Dim filesInRoot = From file In Directory.EnumerateFiles(currentDir, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
For Each file As String In filesInRoot
    Try
        Dim targetPath As String = Path.Combine(targetDir, Path.GetFileName(file))
        IO.File.Move(file, targetPath)
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' log or whatever, here just ignore and continue ...
    End Try
Next
```

Comment: If I use this code, I get an error saying: 'EnumerateFileSystemEntries' is not a member of 'System.IO.Directory'. I use .net framework 3.5. What should I do now?

Comment: @ Tim Schmelter: Yes, but it still gives the same error. It now says 'Directory.EnumerateFiles' is not a member of 'System.IO.Directory'

Comment: @user3752033: that method is new in .NET 4.0, if you are on a lower target framewrok you have to use `Directory.GetDirectories` and `Directory.GetFiles` instead. I hope you are on .NET 3.5, otherwise the LINQ approach is also obsolete. **Edit** But you've tagged Visual Studio 2013

Comment: @ Tim Schmelter: Ok Thanks :)

Comment: @user3752033: but you've tagged Visual Studio 2013, maybe you have to change the compiler settings to use >= 4.0.

Comment: @ Tim Schmelter: I know. But, I want to develop this app which can even run on those machines on which .NET framework 4.0 or higher is not installed. So, I am developing it in .NET framework 3.5

Comment: @ Tim Schmelter: Sorry, but your code only moves files from the current directory, it can't move folders including its files that are located in current directory. Please help.....